# MakeFile not detecting changes on its configuration

Tags: c++, makefile

I am kinda new to using MakeFile, but I think I already somewhat understand how they work. I saw some explanations but I can't figure out why the following occurs:

My school shared a MakeFile for the students to use. It was the following:

```
# Set gcc as the C++ compiler
CXX=g++

# Enforce C++ 2011 as the language standard
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 -pedantic

# Enable all standard warnings, uninitialized variable warnings, 
# and treat all warnings as errors
CXXFLAGS+= -Wall -Wuninitialized -Werror

# Generate code with debugging information
# (for use with a debugger like gdb)
CXXFLAGS+= -g

# Link with math library
CXXFLAGS+= -lm

# Enable ASan (Address Sanitizer) 
# and UBSan (Undefined Behavior Sanitizer)
#
# NOTE: comment these temporarily if 
# your development environment is failing
# due to these settings - it is important that 
# you fix your environment at some point.
CXXFLAGS+=-fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined

# C++ source files to consider in compilation
CPP_FILES=
# C++ header files to consider in compilation
HEADERS=
# Name of executable program ('main' by default)
PROG=main

$(PROG): $(CPP_FILES) $(HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPP_FILES) -o $(PROG)
```

I understood everything, the problem emerges when I try to modify it. Some changes seem to don't have any repercussions on its result.

I wanted that every file compiled resulted in a executable file with a default name, like "rooster", instead of the name of the .cpp file.

The weird thing is that, if I modify the last lines of the MakeFile to:

```
$(PROG): $(CPP_FILES) $(HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPP_FILES) -o rooster
```

The output file is exactly the same as if I had changed nothing.

I tried to search a answer online, but with no success and I check if the MakeFile used to compile was the same I altered, so I added a new target, like:

```
test:
      echo "Yup, same MakeFile"
```

I was expecting it to don't be detected, because if the changes were detected in this case why wouldn't they be detected in the case I mentioned before.

But for my surprise, when I called it, using `make test`, it ran ok.

What am I missing? Is it something to do with the MakeFile in itself or the machine I am using?

Thanks a lot for the help:)

Comment: Why don't you just set `PROG=rooster`?

Comment: What does "Some changes" mean? Can you be more specific, and explain in detail what changes are made to which files, show the before and after timestamp of each file, then show what happens when `make` gets executed.

Comment: You don't have any dependencies on the makefile itself, so any changes you do to the makefile will not trigger any rebuilds. Add a `clean` target that cleans up object file *and* the executable program file, and use that when you make changes to the makefile.

Comment: @fukanchik What would that change? Wouldn't that make the name of the target rooster? But I tried it and the same happens, as if I changed nothing

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The changes I was mentioning were related to the MakeFile itself. I change it so the executable created has a different name from the .cpp file, but nothing occurs

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude How would that be done? Sorry I might have not fully understood

Comment: @Eduardo you wanted to do this `$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPP_FILES) -o **rooster**` which is easier to do by changing `PROG`

Comment: And did the new executable name already exist, and if so what was its timestamp?

Comment: You didn't change `PROG` but you changed the output name. Now `make` wants to create a target `PROG` aka `main`, sees it already exists and does *nothing*. It never calls the compiler with `-o rooster`. That's why nothing changes. Delete `main` and you will get `rooster` (not that this was the correct way to do it).

Comment: A general question because I am getting a little confused. Why does work doing `make cppfilename` ? I assumed `PROG` could actually somehow change based on the parameter given, is that the case?

Comment: You're `PROG` is hardcoded to `main` in the line `PROG=main`.   Actually looking at your code, `CPP_FILES` is also hardcoded to be blank, so by default it won't build anything...  (note, if your command line is `make PROG=rooster CPP_FILES=rooster.c`, then the command line values will override the ones being set in the makefile, so that might work... - see [Overriding Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Overriding.html)).   So how exactly are you using this makefile?

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand how make works.   If you do `make foo`, make will try to build the *target* `foo`.   Currently your makefile only has the target `$(PROG)`, which resolves to `main` if you don't override `PROG` with your command line.   So `make foo` *should* fail with `no rule to make target foo`, and `make cppfilename` *should* fail with `no rule to make cppfilename`.

Note that if you run just `make` (with no arguments), make will try to run the first target it encounters (again `main` in this case).   Note that if the file `main` already exists, and is newer than all its dependencies, make will consider it up to date, and not try to rebuild it.

Now things get a bit more complicated with [Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html) -- that is, if you try to run `make somefile.o`, and a file called `somefile.cpp` exists, and is newer than `somefile.o`, make will use a default rule to try to build it.

Note that make does not know what the name of a file that a target recipe actually generates (make does not speak bash), but it assumes that it will be the name of the target.   So in your example, you had:

```
$(PROG): $(CPP_FILES) $(HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPP_FILES) -o rooster
```

which resolves to

```
main:
    g++ -g -lm -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -o rooster
```

Which will be the default target because it's the first target mentioned.  So `make rooster` should fail with `no rule to make target rooster`, and `make` would fail if no filename `main` already exists because it tries to rebuild it, but when it does, it calls `g++` without any input arguments.   If `main` already exists, it will simply exit, as there's nothing to do.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation:) That makes much more sense, but with the first Makefile configuration I shared, `make filename` would run in the console the comand `g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wuninitialized -Werror -g -lm -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined    filename.cpp   -o filename` . How is this explained? Sorry if it was just me overlooking something you wrote.

Comment: With the makefile you provided, it wouldn't.  It would output `make-3.81: *** No rule to make target 'filename'.  Stop.`  Either you are running `make` from a different directory (and hence not using that makefile), or you didn't include the actual makefile you were running in your post.

Comment: I am pretty sure the directory is right and the Makefile I used is indeed the one I shared. I searched a little bit more and found out that the use of those variable names is on purpose. Their use actually affects the implicit rules. But is there an implicit variable that controls the name of the output file? Makefiles just became a lot more powerful but confusing now

Comment: @Eduardo As already explained in comments there is an [implicit rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) to build `filename` from `filename.cpp`. If `filename.cpp` exists and you type `make filename`, the implicit rule is used. That's why you see what you see. If you type `make foobar` and there is no candidate implicit rule you get an error, instead. Note that, thanks to implicit rules, you don't even need a Makefile in many simple cases. If there are no extra dependencies and the default variable settings are OK `make hello_world` works without a Makefile.